# Print "Hello world" before main() function in C

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, program-entry-point, startup

The following program copied from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/I-want-to-print-Hello-even-before-main-is-executed-How-will-you-acheive-that/answer/Prathamesh-Kulkarni), that print `"Hello world"` before `main()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  return 0;
}

void _start(void)
{
  printf ("hello, world\n");
  int ret = main();
  _exit (ret);
}
```

Then, I compiled above program on Ubuntu-14.04 GCC compiler using following command

```
gcc -nostartfiles hello.c
```

And ran `a.out` executable file, But I got `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`? So, Why **Segmentation fault**?

Comment: `Why I got Segmentation fault?` Have you tried to use a debugger? The answer probably relies in depths of libc implementation, but glibc is open-source and you shouldn't have a problem degugging it. Apparently, you need to install `libc6-dbg` (or `libc-dbg`) to get debug information.

Comment: Are you using `gcc` on Linux system?

Comment: Yes, i use GCC on Ubuntu.

Comment: In C, execution starts with `main`. Whatever makes your program do stuff before `main` is outside of the scope of C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_start` is the real entrypoint of the executable, that is normally taken by the C runtime to initialize its stuff - including stdio -, call functions marked with the `constructor` attribute and then call your `main` entrypoint. If you take it and try to use stuff from the standard library (such as `printf`) you are living dangerously, because you are using stuff that hasn't been initialized yet.

What you *can* do, however, is to bypass the C runtime completely, and print using a straight syscall, such as `write`.